# Swift code fetch value in string

Tags: string, swift

I am using SOAPEngine framework to connect to my webservice and this is the result i want to retrieve from my result string  GetResult ="True";
can you help ? i am working with Swift Xcode 7.3

```
/*
    Result ={
        Body =     {
            GetResponse =         {
                GetResult = "\"True\"";
            };
        };
    }
*/`
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi Eric yes is a dictionary but i am not able to get only GetResult = "True";

Comment: Fix your question.

Comment: To the question "how to get value from a dictionary" the answer is to read the Swift basics documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID113

Comment: ok thx i am beginner  swift developpement

Answer (score 0):

let sonuclar = dict["Body"]!["GetResponse"]!!["GetResult"]